# Reboot the machine from an init.d service

Tags: xubuntu, services, init.d

I'm using an init.d script to launch a kiosk-like application in a xubuntu powered machine. The script looks this way:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     myapp 
# Required-Start:   $syslog $local_fs $remote_fs $named $xdm $lightdm $dbus
# Required-Stop:    $syslog $local_fs $remote_fs 
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description:    Start myapp
# Description:       
#                    
### END INIT INFO

PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
NAME=myapp

export XAUTHORITY=/home/myuser/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY=:0

case "${1}" in
  start)
    xfce4-power-manager
    sudo /sbin/runuser myuser -s /bin/bash -c /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping myapp..."
        killall myscript.sh
        ;;
  restart|reload)
        "$0" stop
        "$0" start
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The `myscript.sh` file launches a NodeJS application and starts a fullscreen sized browser with a non-root user. However, at some point I need the end user to be able to reboot the machine. I'm calling the native `reboot` command from NodeJs and this works when I launch the application from a standard shell (executing `myscript.sh`), but not when I do it as a init.d service. It looks like it lacks some permission. This is the error I get in the `syslog`:

```
Failed to open /dev/initctl: Permission denied
```

Any idea?

Comment: maybe this will help you [Poweroff or Reboot as normal User](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85663/380915)

Comment: you don't need to run runuser with sudo (don't think you need DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY either)

Comment: I forgot to mention: `myuser` already is able to run a `reboot` command without sudo, in a new shell. DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY are used because the service launches a browser as a GUI, actually.